# Moving sharedaddy buttons (in Jetpack) to the top of a post?

Tags: filters, plugin-jetpack

How would one move the sharedaddy buttons included in Jetpack to be placed before a post's or page's content, rather than after it? I see that in `sharing-service.php` the function that prints the buttons is hooked to the_content filter hook: `add_filter( 'the_content', 'sharing_display', 19 );`

I'm not sure what to place in my functions.php file to override that, though. I'm assuming I somehow need to cause the output from `sharing-service.php` to be prepended to `the_content` rather than appended to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically it line 480 in sharing-service.php
where it says:

```
return $text.$sharing_content;
```

and it should be

```
return $sharing_content.$text;
```

now changing that file won't keep your changes on updates so you can copy that function (sharing_display) to your functions.php and rename it to something different say `my_sharing_display` and make the change there.

Next you need to remove the filters that plugin adds and replace with your own so in your functions.php add:

```
//remove old
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'sharing_display');
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'sharing_display');
//add new
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_sharing_display', 19 );
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'my_sharing_display', 19 );
```

### Update

the remove_filter hook is not actually removing because it's missing the priority parameter , from the codex:

> Important: To remove a hook, the $function_to_remove and $priority  arguments must match when the hook was added. This goes for both filters and actions. No warning will be given on removal failure.

so change :

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'sharing_display');
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'sharing_display');
```

to:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'sharing_display',19);
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'sharing_display',19);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That partially worked - the sharing buttons still appear at the bottom of posts (as well as at the top, now). I'm not sure why that `remove_filter` isn't working, but it isn't. Any thoughts?

Comment: @tnorthcutt: yep, i updated the answer

Comment: You can check the return value of `remove_filter` or `remove_action`, if it is `true` the hook was found and removed, otherwise it will be `false`. So you won't get a warning, but you can check the result if it doesn't do what you expected.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
<?php 
if ( function_exists( 'sharing_display' ) ) {
    echo sharing_display();
}
the_content();
?>
```

worked for me

Answer (score -3):

Another option, would be to edit the Jetpack plugin files directly.  Take out both `add_filters()` for `the_content` and `the_excerpt` from sharing-service.php.

Then you can manually put `<?php echo sharing_display(); ?>`  in your theme's loop wherever you want the sharing bar to be located.