# How to change the position of Jetpack sharing icons?

Tags: the-content, plugin-jetpack

[image: Jetpack Sharing buttons settins]
Typically Jetpack sharing buttons target the single page's `the_content()` function and echo the sharing icons just below the content. But for my site, I actually want it to **Disable** for `the_content()`, but to use it in some other `<div>`. I know I can check the "Disable CSS and JS" checkbox to disable the built-in functionality, but I actually don't want to code more and I like the default CSS of Jetpack sharing icons.

I simply want a Javascript code to alter the target of Jetpack so that instead of showing under the `the_content()` I can show it under another custom `<div>` of my choice.

Is it possible with any filter or hook?

P.S.: I just renamed the "Posts" to "Products" for my project. It's nothing to worry about. :)

Comment: First result in Google for "jetpack move sharing buttons": http://jetpack.me/2013/06/10/moving-sharing-icons/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'sharing_display', 19 );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'sharing_display', 19 );

add_filter( 'the_content', 'share_buttons_above_post', 19 );
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'share_buttons_above_post', 19 );

function share_buttons_above_post( $content = '' ) {
if ( function_exists( 'sharing_display' ) ) {
    return sharing_display() . $content;
}
else {
    return $content;
}
}
```

Change the [hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference).

Related info https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/12826/9884

Comment: Thanks for the nice treasure house and the way to modify as desired. But just a little bit: How can I target it to a custom `<div>` of mine with its class, suppose, `<div class="this_div">something custom here</div>`?

Comment: For styling the buttons with your own CSS?

Comment: I placed 3 tabs below the single page. First one is from a plugin "Related posts Thumbnail", second one is "the content" and in third one "comments". So on the first view the sharing buttons are not visible. I want them to be visible under the first tab where the function `get_related_posts_thumbnails()` is showing related posts (if found any).

Comment: Change the hook position and/or 3rd parameter for positioning priority.

Comment: Ok. Got my answer from Matts' answer from the link you provided. Thanks for your answer. Marking as accepted.